# Inversion after "only now"

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

I was wondering if the following sentence was grammatically correct:

"Only now am I sure who is my real friend."

I found it in my grammar book and I am confused.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not really. The subject-auxiliary inversion ("_am I"_) is fine and occurs as a result of fronting the adverb "only". But there should not be inversion in the subordinate interrogative clause, which should be _who my real friend is_.

Comment: ... Fine – and necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> Not really. The subject-auxiliary inversion ("*am I"*) is fine and occurs as a result of fronting the adverb "only". But there should not be inversion in the subordinate interrogative clause, which should be *who my real friend is*.